# Android how to get a gif in the center of the screen and to the front like a 'ProgressDialog'?

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

So when I click on an activity I want to show a loading gif, instead of a: 'ProgessDialog', but how can I bring this in the center of the screen and to the front without replacing other objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_translucent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="24dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Add to your build.gradle(Module.app)

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
```

In your Activity

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageGif)
            .asGif()
            .fitCenter()
            .crossFade()
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Just some reputation

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent library for this called [andorid-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

You'd want to do this, after adding the library to your project:

`<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/src_drawable_here"
    />`

Make sure it's inside a layout that allows center in parent (which means center horizontally and vertically), such as a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I'm already using this one, but at 1 page I got some trouble with it because it's using multiple layouts.

Comment: I found out that you need to use a: 'FrameLayout'.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
    <FrameLayout> <!-- this can also be a CoordinatorLayout -->

        ... (content)


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrim"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/dark_translucent"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="24dp"
                android:indeterminate="true"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

This is used in conjunction with a loader. When the loader is started, I set the scrim visibility to `visible`.  When the loader completes, I set the scrim visibility back to `gone`.

A couple things:

- You should track whether the scrim is visible or not in the saved instance state, so if the user rotates the device while the loader is in progress, you can show the scrim again immediately in `onCreate`.
- If you are covering touchable controls, you should make all your controls disabled until completion.  Alternatively, you could set an `onTouchListener` on the scrim layout to consume the touch events so the content controls are effectively disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I already got an option (sorry), but I have some troubles at 1 form, because I want to make it visible in an AsyncTask class, but I can't see it.